# Understanding Java code linking in classes.dex

Tags: java, android

Is there any dynamic linking to classes outside of classes.dex when running Android app at device? Or all the Java (Dalvik) code is inside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there most definitely is extensive dynamic linkage to code contained in other files, the most obvious example of which would be the device-wide file(s) which implement the platform APIs.

Also note that the code actually executed is (primarly? always?) that from the odex (optimized dex) files generated on install, rather than the dex file in the apk.

Comment: Is there somewhere an explanation how to remove maximal amount of code from classes.dex? I have seen as small as 10K files while basic application from ADT is 700K.Is there any reason that so much code is hold inside of the classes.dex?

Comment: Are you using proguard?  Reverse engineering tools will show what is actually in yours.